# How to enable Serverless SQL warehouses in Azure DataBricks through Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I am trying to deploy an SQL Warehouse in Azure DataBricks of type `serverless`. For this I intend to use the `databricks` Terraform provider, where the SQL warehouse can be created with the [databricks_sql_endpoint](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/sql_endpoint) resource type.

However, as I understand, you need to enable the "Serverless SQL warehouses" option in the Admin settings first.

[image: Azure DataBricks Admin Settings]

I have not been able to find how to enable this option through Terraform in the [DataBricks provider documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs). Nor have I found a solution elsewhere. My question is if anyone knows if it's possible to configure this option through Terraform.

---

My resource definition in Terraform looks like this:

```
resource "databricks_sql_endpoint" "this" {
  name = "Standard"
  cluster_size = "2X-Small"
  min_num_clusters = 1
  max_num_clusters = 2
  auto_stop_mins = 30
  
  enable_serverless_compute = true
  warehouse_type = "PRO"
}
```

This results in the following error:

> "Error: cannot create sql endpoint: Serverless Compute is not enabled
> in Databricks SQL Workspace config. Please reach out to your
> administrator."

Answer (score 4):

I discoverd that serverless compute can be enabled using the `databricks_sql_global_config` resource type. The following code enables the serverless compute option globally and subsequently deploys a SQL warehouse with the serverless compute option enabled.

```
resource "databricks_sql_global_config" "this" {
  data_access_config        = {}
  enable_serverless_compute = true
}

resource "databricks_sql_endpoint" "this" {
  depends_on       = [databricks_sql_global_config.this]
  name             = "Standard"
  cluster_size     = "2X-Small"
  min_num_clusters = 1
  max_num_clusters = 2
  auto_stop_mins   = 30

  enable_serverless_compute = true
  warehouse_type            = "PRO"
}
```

I did notice that running `terraform plan` throws the following warning:

> Warning: Argument is deprecated
>
> with databricks_sql_global_config.this,   on main.tf line 189, in
> resource "databricks_sql_global_config" "this":  189:
> enable_serverless_compute = true
>
> This field is intended as an internal API and may be removed from the
> Databricks Terraform provider in the future

However, it resulted in a successful deployment. Perhaps it's because Serverless SQL Warehouses currently is a Preview feature in Azure DataBricks. I am using version `1.14.3` of the databricks provider.